# How to create a new GitHub account with the same email address?

Tags: github, account

We are using GitHub Enterprise 2.5.1.

In our company, when a user switches to a new role, a new AD account will be created for him, with a new set of permissions. e.g. my current account is "huj" as a developer with email address "Jirong_Hu@otpp.com, if I become a BA, then:

1. The old account "huj" will be marked as "OIM Deletion" in AD.
2. A new account called "huj2" will be created for me, with the same old email address, Jirong_Hu@otpp.com.

My questions are:

1. As account is automatically created upon login, if I login to GitHub with the new account "huj2", I got this error: Unable to create the user because email Jirong_Hu@otpp.com is already taken and emails is invalid.
2. How can I create the new account "huj2" in GitHub, with the same old email address.
3. What's the consequence of doing the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to resolve this issue:

1. If the existing user has no activity, then delete this existing account.
2. Otherwise change his email to something else, then when the new user logs in, a new account will be created.

Answer (score 74):

I know this is an old post but it still shows at the top on a Google search on this subject.

Some email providers support using special characters to use multiple email addresses that map to a single account.
For example, if you use Gmail and your email address is `myemail@gmail.com` and you already have an account on GitHub with that email you can create a new GitHub account using `myemail+1@gmail.com`

Comment: Thank you so much! This also works with outlook.com. And the email can have any number of characters after the + (such as `myemail+test@outlook.com`)

Comment: Wow... This is cool. Thanks! Just went to go look up more info and saw [this](https://gizmodo.com/how-to-use-the-infinite-number-of-email-addresses-gmail-1609458192). It also works with periods `first.last@gmail.com == firstlast@gmail.com`.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer is NO.
You can't create more than 1 ID in GitHub by the same email, but you can do it by using multiple email IDs.

If you try to do it, GitHub will show an error - "email invalid or already taken", so delete the present account or make it with a new email id .